# Using Numba to improve finite-differences laplacian

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am using Python to solve a reaction-diffusion system of equations ([Fitz-Hugh-Nagumo model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FitzHugh%E2%80%93Nagumo_model)). I would like to learn how to use Numba in order to accelerate the calculation. I am currently importing the following laplacian.py module to my integration script:

```
def neumann_laplacian_1d(u,dx2):
    """Return finite difference Laplacian approximation of 2d array.
    Uses Neumann boundary conditions and a 2nd order approximation.
    """
    laplacian = np.zeros(u.shape)
    laplacian[1:-1] =  ((1.0)*u[2:] 
                       +(1.0)*u[:-2]
                       -(2.0)*u[1:-1])
    # Neumann boundary conditions
    # edges
    laplacian[0]  =  ((2.0)*u[1]-(2.0)*u[0])
    laplacian[-1] =  ((2.0)*u[-2]-(2.0)*u[-1])

    return laplacian/ dx2
```

Where `u` is a NumPy 1D array that stands for one of the fields. I tried to add the decorator `@autojit(target="cpu")` after importing `from numba import autojit`. I didn't see any improvement in the calculation. Could anyone give me a hint how to use Numba properly in this case?

The input array I have used here is

```
a = random.random(252)
```

And so I've compared the performance with the line:

```
%timeit(neumann_laplacian_1d(a,1.0))
```

With Numba I got:

```
%timeit(neumann_laplacian_1d(a,1.0))
The slowest run took 22071.00 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1 loops, best of 3: 14.1 µs per loop
```

Without Numba I got (!!):

```
%timeit(neumann_laplacian_1d(a,1.0))
The slowest run took 11.84 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.12 µs per loop
```

Numba actually make it slower..

Comment: Do you have some sample input for testing? Do you have some performance measures to show?

Comment: Which version of numba are you using? Also, if you try writing the operations as explicit for loops over scalar elements, do you see a difference? What is the size of `u`?

Comment: @JoshAdel I use numba 0.21.0 -  `print numba.__version__
0.21.0`

Comment: @M4rtini I have added the commands I have used to compare the runs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to replicate your results.

Python version: 3.4.4 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 19 2016, 12:10:59) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]

numba version: 0.23.1

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def neumann_laplacian_1d(u,dx2):
    """Return finite difference Laplacian approximation of 2d array.
    Uses Neumann boundary conditions and a 2nd order approximation.
    """
    laplacian = np.zeros(u.shape)
    laplacian[1:-1] =  ((1.0)*u[2:] 
                       +(1.0)*u[:-2]
                       -(2.0)*u[1:-1])
    # Neumann boundary conditions
    # edges
    laplacian[0]  =  ((2.0)*u[1]-(2.0)*u[0])
    laplacian[-1] =  ((2.0)*u[-2]-(2.0)*u[-1])

    return laplacian/ dx2

@nb.autojit(nopython=True)
def neumann_laplacian_1d_numba(u,dx2):
    """Return finite difference Laplacian approximation of 2d array.
    Uses Neumann boundary conditions and a 2nd order approximation.
    """
    laplacian = np.zeros(u.shape)
    laplacian[1:-1] =  ((1.0)*u[2:] 
                       +(1.0)*u[:-2]
                       -(2.0)*u[1:-1])
    # Neumann boundary conditions
    # edges
    laplacian[0]  =  ((2.0)*u[1]-(2.0)*u[0])
    laplacian[-1] =  ((2.0)*u[-2]-(2.0)*u[-1])

    return laplacian/ dx2

a = np.random.random(252)
#run once to make the JIT do it's work before timing
neumann_laplacian_1d_numba(a, 1.0)


%timeit neumann_laplacian_1d(a, 1.0)
%timeit neumann_laplacian_1d_numba(a, 1.0)

>>10000 loops, best of 3: 21.5 µs per loop
>>The slowest run took 4.49 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
>>100000 loops, best of 3: 3.53 µs per loop
```

I see similar results for python 2.7.11 and numba 0.23

```
>>100000 loops, best of 3: 19.1 µs per loop
>>The slowest run took 8.55 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
>>100000 loops, best of 3: 2.4 µs per loop
```

Comment: I've update Numba and I also see improvement in the performance when I use Numba. The question is whether I will still see this improvement if I import this module from a different file (this case, a class that implements the FHN mathematical model). As I understood there is a bit of an issue in working with Numba together with classes..